# Como reemplazar más de un espacio por uno solo en DB2

Tags: db2

Tengo una columna llamada ***NombreCliente*** que contiene el siguiente dato:

```
'CABEZAS     CIFUENTES   JOSEPH'
```

Como puedo lograr para eliminar todos los espacios por un "único espacio", de tal manera que luzca así:

```
'CABEZAS CIFUENTES JOSEPH'
```

He probado con *REPLACE('CABEZAS     CIFUENTES   JOSEPH', '  ', ' ')* y también *TRIM*, pero no he conseguido solución.

Recordar que estoy utilizando DB2.

Agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de utilizar la función REGEXP_REPLACE que reemplaza expresiones regulares, en este caso, le indicaríamos la expresión regular \s+ que busca 1 o más ocurrencias de espacios y le diríamos que lo reemplace por un único espacio, desde la posición 1 y todas las veces que lo encuentre.

[Documentación de db2](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-regexp-replace)

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('CABEZAS     CIFUENTES   JOSEPH', '\s+', ' ', 1, 0, '') as resultado
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```